# TikZ node with UML comment shape

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I'm wondering how could I draw node that looks like ** UML comment **.
Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: The PGF manual contains an example for creating exactly this node shape in the section "Declaring New Shapes".

Comment: If you want to create UML diagrams with tikz, you should look at [TikZ-UML](http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/index.php?lang=en).

Answer (score 6):

As it is stated in the [tikz manual](http://texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf), there is no UML support in TikZ at the moment [p. 791]. So you might find [MetaUML](http://metauml.sourceforge.net/old/index.html) interesting, and especially their [notes](http://metauml.sourceforge.net/old/notes.html).

If you have installed MetaUML, simply save the following code as `name.mp` and type in the console `mptopdf name.mp`:

```
input metauml;
input TEX;

beginfig(5);
  Note.A("This class implements the formula:", 
          TEX("$\sum_1^n f(x)\cdot dx$"));
  drawObjects(A);
endfig;

end
```

You'll get this result as `name.pdf`.

[image: Example of a Note in MetaUML]

So you have to define your UML structure externally and then just include the pdf in your document.

Have Fun!

Comment: that's not what i want, it it is not how to do it in tikz

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for the advise, I hope my answer is now more helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Meter reply, have created **umlnote.sty**

```
\ProvidesPackage{umlnote}

\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows}
    
\pgfdeclareshape{umlnote} {
    \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle]
    \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
    \backgroundpath{
        \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
        \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
        \pgf@xc=\pgf@xb \advance\pgf@xc by-5pt
        \pgf@yc=\pgf@yb \advance\pgf@yc by-5pt
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yb}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yc}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
        \pgfpathclose
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yb}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yc}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}
    }
}

% Key to add font macros to the current font
\tikzset{add font/.code={\expandafter\def\expandafter\tikz@textfont\expandafter{\tikz@textfont#1}}} 

% Define default style for this node
\tikzset{umlnote/port labels/.style={font=\sffamily}}
\tikzset{every umlnote node/.style={draw, inner sep=2mm, outer sep=0pt,font=\scriptsize}}
```

use as

```
\usepackage{umlnote}
... in document
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[umlnote,minimum width=2cm, text width=2cm] at (0,0) (note1) {This some uml comment blah blah blah...};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The result

[image: umlnote example]

Answer (score 0):

```
\pgfdeclareshape{umlnote}
    {
        \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle]
        \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
        \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
        \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
        \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}
        \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}
        \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
        \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}
        \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}
        \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
        \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
        \backgroundpath{
            \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
            \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
            \pgf@xc=\pgf@xb \advance\pgf@xc by-5pt
            \pgf@yc=\pgf@yb \advance\pgf@yc by-5pt
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yb}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yc}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
            \pgfpathclose
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yb}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yc}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}
        }
    }
```

copied from documentation

Comment: Does it work? If so could you post a working example, because solely `\usepackage{tikz}` and the shapes library are not enough to make this work.

Comment: You should consider improving your answer. First of all because it doesn't provide a minimal working example. Second because it doesn't provide any insight into how it solves your problem. Anybody else who hasn't read the `pgf` manual would not be able to make sense out of this.

Comment: please don't downvote own answers.